# "Show row weights" in views not working

Tags: views

All views in my drupal site lost "Show row weights" function. Everytime when clicks "Show row weights" link, its text will change to "hide row weights". But there is no weight column in view table.

Here is a screenshot showing what I am encoutering:

[image]

[image]

This issue has been struggling me for quite a while. Many thanks if anyone can offer some ideas about it.

Cheers!

Comment: Have you changed the version of jQuery that you're using?